# Basic XML Editing and Saving

Tags: xml, notepad++, powerpivot

I've been shown a workaround that allows users to bulk create DAX measures in PowerPivot however I am struggling to successfully edit then save the XML file in question.

Basically I open the XML file in IE then copy and paste the code into Notepad++, I then make the necessary additions to the code before saving the file to my desktop as 'item211.xml'. The problem is that if I try and open the file I have created I see nothing in the browser and my new file is much smaller than the original one.

Am I missing something very simple?

Regards
Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protip:  open the XML file in Notepad++, and save it with Notepad++, and then never use IE ever again.